# Pointwise convergence of sine series of $x^{-2}$

Tags: fourier-series

I was wondering if the sine series of $x^{-2}$ converges pointwise on the open interval $(0,1)$.

What is the most general criterion to ensure pointwise convergence of a Fourier series?

Comment: If the function is piecewise continuous on an interval, then the Fourier series converges pointwise.

Answer (score 3):

Some results about pointwise convergence: [list in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence), [notes on the Dini test](http://math.mit.edu/~jerison/103/handouts/fseries.extra.pdf). There is no such thing as *the most general criterion*.

The function $x^{-2}$ on the interval $(0,1)$ does not have a Fourier series, since it is not integrable. So the question of its convergence is moot.